# need inputs on how to pytest (mock) a method that is returning a query result from db

Tags: postgresql, mocking, pytest, patch, python-3.8

I have a python code, that creates cursor and runs a query.
I want to unittest it with pytest framework. I have read many articles but I am not able to absorb the concept as I am very new to programming.

I am using pg8000 db connection

I have gone through almost all the articles on google, but can't get the concept of this particular scenario. What to mock and how will actual result work. What to assert etc.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Code Snippets below:
Main.py

```
def sql(connection, query)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    result = cursor.execute(query)
    cursor.close()
    return result

test.py

def test_sql():

    mock_con = MagicMock()
    mock_con = mock_con.return_value
    mock_cur = mock_con.cursor.return_value
    
    cur = main.sql(mock_connect, 'query')

    assert mock_connect.cursor() ==mock_cur
    assert mock_cur == cursor
    assert mock_connect.call_count = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed a little bit your test, this is working:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

def sql(connection, query):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    result = cursor.execute(query)
    cursor.close()
    return result

def test_sql():

    mock_con = MagicMock()

    cur = sql(mock_con, 'query')

    assert isinstance(mock_con.cursor(), MagicMock)
    mock_con.cursor().execute.assert_called_with("query")
```

You can run by putting this in a file and `pytest file.py`

You were comparing cursor instance, which does not make sense, since you will compare MagicMock instance instead of call arguments, which is usually the goal when mocking

Comment: thanks, can you please explain what exactly are we testing with that test code? basically we are not using "cur" anywhere, but the cursor from the actual method ?

Comment: Because while evaluating the last two assert statements, I am getting result as None. shouldn't it say True or False?

Comment: The first assert checks if the cursor is a instance of the mock, which is quite useless.

But the second, checks if cursor.execute was called with the parameter "query"


result here will be a magicMock instance, because you are using mock. You can add a return value if you want